# Use LINQ to search items in a SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, linq, sorteddictionary

I have a SortedDictionary of the type:

```
SortedDictionary<PriorityType, List<T>> dictionary;
```

where PriorityType is an Enum class, and the List contains various string values.

I want to use LINQ to search for the string items in the list, that have an even length.
As in:

```
IEnumerable<T> filteredList = new List<T>();  

// Stores items in list whose string length is even
filteredList = //LINQ code;
```

I have tried a lot of implementations of LINQ but, it seems tough to traverse a List in a SortedDictionary using LINQ (taking into account I'm relatively new to LINQ).

Please help me with the LINQ code. Thanks!

Comment: What are "Keys that have an even length"?

Comment: I want the items in the Lists that have an even length. Edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you need items from lists which have even count of items:

```
filteredList = dictionary.Select(kvp => kvp.Value)
                         .Where(l => l != null && l.Count % 2 == 0)
                         .SelectMany(l => l)
                         .ToList();
```

UPDATE: If you want to select strings with even length, then you should use `List<string>` instead of generic list of `T`:

```
SortedDictionary<PriorityType, List<string>> dictionary;
filteredList = dictionary.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value)
                         .Where(s => s.ToString().Length % 2 == 0)
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: This give me the string items in the lists only when the list has even number of string elements. However, I want all the string items that have an even length.

Comment: @nashcheez sorry, but what strings you are talking about? You have generic `List<T>` which can be list of integers or any class

Comment: Yes it's a generic list! And I am passing strings into it from Main() i.e. It becomes List<string> when the SortedDictionary is implemented.

Comment: @nashcheez you have generic dictionary. So query also should be generic. It should work with any T type. Use `SortedDictionary<PriorityType, List<string>>` if you want to work with strings

Comment: Yes it should be generic. And for testing purposes I am using String. But I can find all the strings that have an even length. That's why I'm seeking help.

Comment: @nashcheez if list is generic, then T does not have length

Comment: Yes but I am converting it as such: 'item.ToString().Length' which will work for all T types.

Comment: @nashcheez then use `s => s.ToString().Length % 2 == 0` with my last query. But your requirement is really strange

Comment: Yes my requirement was strange, I admit. I had earlier implemented a Priority queue! And then I had to modify it to implement `IEnumerable<T>` interface to extend the T type's capabilities with various extension methods like Where(…). Anyways, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @Sergey is correct & in conformance to my requirements.

Also I found another easy solution using the `select` statement.

```
filteredList = from list in dictionary.Values from item in list where item.ToString().Length % 2 == 0 select item;
```

Hope this helps!